# Why does LocalStorage work strange with arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

**Problems**:

When I enter something and click **SEND** the elements are sorted as a list `<ul><li></li></ul>` (good thing) but after reloading the page the data appears as a string: `one,two,three`.

If after reloading the page you type something and click SEND the new item will appear *under the string as a list*.

But if you try reloading one more time you will see a **new string**.

You won't see `one,two,three,new element`.

But only: `new element`.

As if the data only lasted one session.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// ARRAY
const tasks = [];

// WHEN USER CLICK BUTTON
btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);

// ADD A TASK
function addTask() {
  tasks.push(input.value);

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  container.appendChild(li);

  localStorage.setItem("task", tasks);
}

container.innerText = localStorage.getItem("task");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="btn">SEND</button>

<ul id="container">
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**
I tried with `stringify()` and `parse()`, but the problem persists. After reloading the page, the list appears as a string and old values disappear and are replaced by new ones.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// ARRAY
const tasks = [];

// WHEN USER CLICK BUTTON
btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);

// ADD A TASK
function addTask() {
  tasks.push(input.value);

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  container.appendChild(li);

  localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

container.innerText = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
```

Comment: Local storage stores a string, if you want to maintain a data structure, you should turn it into JSON before storing (And parse it when reading it out)

Comment: localStorage values can only be strings (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)) so when you write an array to localStorage you get its string representation i.e. `'one,two,three'`

Comment: I tried with stringify() and parse(), but the problem persists. After reloading the page, the list appears as a string and old values disappear and are replaced by new ones.

Comment: it's because you just inner text it - you would need to loop through the array and create and append your `li`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage is a key value storage

value can only be string

and idea to solve your issue is to transform your structure with `JSON.stringify(`and recover it with `JSON.parse`

```
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// ARRAY
const tasks = [];

// WHEN USER CLICK BUTTON
btn.addEventListener("click", addTask);


function createLi(value) {
  tasks.push(value);

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  container.appendChild(li);
}

// ADD A TASK
function addTask() {
  createLi(input.value);
  localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task")).forEach(task => {
  createLi(task);
});
```

Comment: I tried with stringify() and parse(), but the problem persists. After reloading the page, the list appears as a string and old values disappear and are replaced by new ones.

Comment: don't forget to reaffect task array with already saved task to be able to manipulate save data. I can propose you to create a function for this i update my reply in consequencies